# ThinkPad X1 Yoga G6: increased CPU usage and heating during suspend, how to find out from logs

Tags: suspend, thinkpad, fan, overheating, log

In the last several weeks, all of a sudden, my ThinkPad X1 Yoga G6 started to overheat *after* suspend, in the bag. The fan is on full speed, and the laptop is extremely hot. On opening the screen, it doesn't boot as normal, and I have to force shut down and reboot for it to wake up. It worked  wonderfully with suspend until just a few weeks ago, so I'm not sure what's going on, or how to debug this.

I'm worried this will lead to damage if it keeps happening, and otherwise I'll have to shut down fully each time I need to transport my laptop.

I would like to know if during suspend something is keeping it up, and increasing CPU usage. OTOH, maybe it is the BIOS that's starting up the fan, and due to being in the laptop bag, it actually increases the heat?

Any pointers on logs to read and settings to check to debug this would be highly appreciated!

My kernel:

```bsh
 λ uname -r
5.14.0-1029-oem
```

```
BIOS           = N32ET71W (1.47 )
Release        = Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Kernel         = 5.14.0-1029-oem #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 13:27:43 UTC 2022 x86_64
```

Comment: Being in a bag will restrict airflow and force an already hot machine to spin the fans up to release the heat, which will warm the bag, which will radiate the heat back into the case, which will keep the machine warmer longer, which will have the fans spin faster and faster as they try to evacuate the heat ... which *can* lead to damage of your battery; the other hardware will survive. What you'll want to do is check `/var/log/syslog` to see where the system is pausing before going to sleep. Once you know which service is not releasing, you'll be in a better position to resolve the issue ‍

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue. Also on Ubuntu 20 LTS, Thinkpad X1 Yoga gen 6.

This has 100% nothing to do with CPU temperature, my laptop is currently suspended and the fans go on and off as they please. The laptop is ice cold. Also, as soon as i flip it open and use it for a minute the fans turn off.

You can enable S3 Sleep in BIOS, this fixes the fan issue but then your trackpad will no longer work properly after suspending. Choose the lesser evil.

I could post my `/var/log/syslog` here but it is pretty long.

Edit: One re-occuring event in syslog. This line/event happens during suspend and 3Mb worth of file size

```
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880239] usb 5-2.1.1.2: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 0
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880240] usb 5-2.1.1.2: 2:0: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880274] systemd-journald[329]: /dev/kmsg buffer overrun, some messages lost.
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880502] usb 5-2.1.1.2: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 0
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880504] usb 5-2.1.1.2: 2:0: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880506] usb 5-2.1.1.2: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 1
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880507] usb 5-2.1.1.2: 2:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880508] usb 5-2.1.1.2: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 0
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880509] usb 5-2.1.1.2: 2:0: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880531] usb 5-2.1.1.2: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 0
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880532] usb 5-2.1.1.2: 2:0: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880533] systemd-journald[329]: /dev/kmsg buffer overrun, some messages lost.
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880533] usb 5-2.1.1.2: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 1
Apr 21 18:10:38 thinkpad-x1 kernel: [126708.880535] usb 5-2.1.1.2: 2:1: usb_set_interface failed (-19)
```

I also noticed that this issue happens more often after using my Docking station (also a Lenovo one)